# Header image not showing

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="page">
<header>
    <img srs="catlogo.jpg" alt= "logo" width= "100px" height= "100px" />
    <h1><center>Mobile Cat Grooming Service</center></h1>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    width: 96%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #660066;
    padding: 2%;

}
header img {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #660066;
}
```

Trying to add a logo to the top left of my website header; however it is not showing. The box is, just not the image. Honestly I doubt I've done a whole lot of right things here.

Comment: Alright, my class mate spotted it at the exact same time. I'm an idiot. False call, thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote:

```
<img srs="catlogo.jpg" alt="logo" width="100px" height="100px" />
```

It should be `src`, not `srs`:

```
<img src="catlogo.jpg" alt="logo" width="100px" height="100px" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use src="" instead of srs="" :)